How to optimise a SQL query for large dataset
I have the following SQL query that does exactly what I need.
WITH Subquery AS (
    SELECT t1.ID
    FROM [SEO].[dbo].[tModelPOEF] t1
    RIGHT JOIN [SEO].[dbo].[tHistory] t2 
      ON (
       (t1.N1 = t2.N1 OR t1.N2 = t2.N1 OR t1.N3 = t2.N1 
           OR t1.N4 = t2.N1 OR t1.N5 = t2.N1 OR t1.N6 = t2.N1)
        )
    WHERE t1.N1 IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE [SEO].[dbo].[tModelPOEF]
SET Filter = CASE WHEN Subquery.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM [SEO].[dbo].[tModelPOEF]
LEFT JOIN Subquery ON tModelPOEF.ID = Subquery.ID

The query is fast enough when the two dataset are small (i.e. tModelPOEF < 10 million rows and tHistory 4000 rows).
However, in some instances, the tModelPOEF table can hold more than 50 million rows. When that happens the query becomes extremely slow when executed.
I was wondering if there is a way I could optimise the query for faster performance

i think your query can be rewritten as: update t set filter = case when exists(select 1 from history h where h.N1 = t.N1...) then 1 else 0 end from tModelPOEF t

Try UNION instead of OR. link

Is your intention to UPDATE everyrow in the table, regardless of a row is found it the other table? Why use a RIGHT JOIN to only turn it onto an INNER JOIN?

We need to see your execution plan (using Paste The Plan)

You don't use t2 fields in your sub-query and always return t1.ID when t1.N1 is not null. So surely you can simplify to just an Update. Update tModelPOEF SET Filter = CASE WHEN N1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Why use a right outer join, when the same thing can be written with a simple left outer join? And then after outer joining t1, you dismiss all outer joined rows with WHERE t1.N1 IS NOT NULL and end up with an inner join, as Thom A correctly mentions. And then you outer join the subquery in order to use CASE WHEN Subquery.ID ... instead of simply putting the subquery there. You made every effort it seems to get the query hard to read. I suggest you take siggemannen's advice and get thus to a much more readable query. Additionally, you can use t2.n1 IN (t1.n1, t1.n2, ...) for readability.

The query is malformed. The right join doesn't make sense since you are negating it with the predicate t1.N1 IS NOT NULL.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

The ORs in your join condition are the performance killer, causing repeated table scans within a nested loop find all matches.
The fix is to restructure the query so that it can perform separate index seeks for each of the 6 columns to be matched. Often this can be done with a UNION to combine the results from the separate subqueries, possibly wrapped up in a OUTER APPLY or a CTE.
UPDATE m
SET Filter = ISNULL(h.Filter, 0)
FROM dbo.tModelPOEF m
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 1 AS Filter FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N1
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Filter FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N2
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Filter FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N3
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Filter FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N4
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Filter FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N5
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Filter FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N6
) h

However, since we are are only checking for existence, the same can also be accomplished with a series of EXISTS() tests that are ORed together in a case expression.
UPDATE m
SET Filter = CASE
   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N1)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N2)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N3)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N4)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N5)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h WHERE h.N1 = m.N6)
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.tModelPOEF m

I also found that the following works. Although the execution plan appears more complicated, I believe the combination of merge-interval, nested-loop, and index seek should provide comparable performance.
UPDATE m
SET Filter = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM dbo.tHistory h
       WHERE h.N1 IN (m.N1, m.N2, m.N3, m.N4, m.N5, m.N6)
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.tModelPOEF m

Each of the above will perform multiple index seeks instead of a table scan to check for matches. However, for this to work, you need to have an appropriate index to support these index seeks.
CREATE INDEX IX_tHistory_N1 ON tHistory(N1)

See this db<>fiddle for a demo that shows the execution plans for the original query plus each of the above against some fabricated test data.
I suggest that you perform your own performance testing using real data before choosing your solution.
Sample results (based on tHistory.N1 values of 101..108:



ID
N1
N2
N3
N4
N5
N6
Filter
Notes




1
101
0
0
0
0
0
True
Match


2
0
102
0
0
0
0
True
Match


3
0
0
103
0
0
0
True
Match


4
0
0
0
104
0
0
True
Match


5
0
0
0
0
105
0
True
Match


6
0
0
0
0
0
106
True
Match


7
0
0
0
0
0
0
False
No match


8
107
0
107
0
108
0
True
Multiple match


9
0
201
0
202
0
0
False
No match




Thanks a lot for the code. The option using EXISTS is fast, however looks like doesn't take into consideration the fact that the h.N have to belong to the same ID

@Marco_sbt - The only ID column referenced in your original query was tModelPOEF.ID, which then became Subquery.ID.  Since tModelPOEF only appears once in each of the above, there is no need to compare that column to itself. Perhaps you omitted logic to match tModelPOEF.ID with some column from the tHistory table. If so, it shouldn't be hard to add that check to the above.
